# Get text between curly brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to get text out of the curly brackets of this text:

```
circle(265.17373,-53.674312,1") # text={1}
circle(265.17373,-53.674312,2") # text={2}
```

For the stuff between parenthesis I use this and that works

```
array = np.append(array, np.array([float(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", line)]))
```

But I also want the text inside of the curly brackets.

```
array2 = np.append(array2, np.array([float(x) for x in re.findall(r"/\{([^}]+)\}/", line)]))
```

But that does not give back anything.

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` also will give you the number present inside the `{...}`

Comment: What do you mean by "accolades"? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accolade If you mean "curly brackets" or "curly braces" be advised they are not called "accolades" in any dialect of English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the forward slash present inside the second line of code.

```
array2 = np.append(array2, np.array([float(x) for x in re.findall(r"\{([^}]+)\}", line)]
```